# Connecting an IDE ULTRA ATA-6 2.5" hard disk to a IDE desktop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

[image]I have an IDE ULTRA ATA-6 2.5" internal laptop hard disk - its model is HTS541080G9AT00.

From my research I understand it has an IDE ULTRA ATA-6 interface. Since I need to recover some files, what kind of adapter do I need in order to connect it to my desktop which is using a IDE 3.5" hard disk?

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between IDE on an 2.5" HDD compared to a 3.5" HDD is that the connector contains both power and data.

Therefore you only need an passive IDE 2.5" to 3.5" adapter like this:

[image]

Alternatively you can buy a universal USB to IDE (2.5 & 3.5) adapter like jap1968 proposed.

Comment: hmm i still dun quite understand how the passive IDE 2.5 adapter will help. maybe i got it wrong. let me take a pic n upload soon

Comment: Using the adaptor above you connect the lower black end to your 2.5" disk and the white power connector (left) to your PSU, then the upper part of the black connector plugs into your IDE cable.

Comment: okay i try. i look for this passive IDE 2.5 adapter

Comment: http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?InvtId=2020-OTB I agree with him but I'd use this one instead.  Cheap and USB so you ain't gotta crack open your reader box.

Answer (score 0):

In our company we have some HDD to USB docks. These devices support 3.5 and 2.5 IDE disks as well as SATA disks of any size. The adapters are very cheap and are very useful to recover disk contents. You do not have even to open the computer case to attach the disk.

Comment: I am curious as to why this would have been voted down.  It's the exact same thing as other solutions except like my own it negates the need to open the case.  These things are actually quite bombtastic so please explain WHY that would not be an acceptable solution since it does EXACTLY what the requester wants and easier than most of the other answers?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It just was trying to share what I consider useful according to my own experience.

Comment: Looked useful to me.  Those things are great.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to connect the drive internally to the motherboard:

[Best item to use is an IDE to usb adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152), that way you can use it on other drives when needed, this one includes sata adaptability also

Answer (score 0):

Just get an adapter.  The one below or the one that Robert suggested would work fine.

[image: 2.5" to 3.5" Laptop IDE Hard Disk HDD Adapter] can also be seen [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0010MKARA)